# problems of python installation

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, dependencies

by trying to install any application on Ubuntu 16.04 
it gives me this message on the terminal 
I understand that I made a mistake by stalling python 2.6.8 by mistake 
so I try to setup python 2.7.12 but give me the same message 
how to solve this problem?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
checkinstall is already the newest version (1.6.2-4ubuntu1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 playonlinux : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-apt : Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but 2.6.8-1 is to be installed
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-minimal : Breaks: python (<= 2.7.3-1~) but 2.6.8-1 is to be installed
 python-pycurl : Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but 2.6.8-1 is to be installed
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-software-properties : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.8-1 is to be installed
 python-talloc : Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but 2.6.8-1 is to be installed
 python-wxgtk3.0 : Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but 2.6.8-1 is to be installed
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-wxversion : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                    Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just running the command `sudo apt-get -f install`, as the message recommended.

Comment: I do that and it gives me this message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)